# how to chroot a python app?

Tags: python, chroot, chroot-jail

I created a simple app in python flask, I would like to put it in a chroot. a very thin jail only containing the bare minimum for this app to run. This is for a school project so I need to use chroot. I'd like to know:

1. how to know which libraries I should put in my chroot (since ldd won't work on the script)
2. how to implement this chroot (the big lines).

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

edit:

thank to some advice I was able to use pyinstaller to make my flask app an executable then use common chroot methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to compile python to binary executable and use standard practices for `chroot`. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057634/2908599) how to compile to binary.

> 1. First, install cython
> 2. Then, you can use cython to generate a C file out of the Python .py file
>    (in reference to > https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040484/5714445)
> 3. Use GCC to compile it after getting your current python version
>    (Note: The below assumes you  are trying to compile it to Python3)

Comment: how can I add the flask library in the compilation process ?

Comment: @lolozen, I think when you translate python to C this library will be included.

Comment: I used pyinstaller instead and it compiled now I need to try to chroot the output